# How to remove a line from the location list?

Tags: location-list

I have a location list populated with around 50 lines, and I would like to remove some of these. Is there a way?

Specifically, I searched for references of a Java method and the LSP (using coc-java) filled the references, but most are to test classes, which do not interest me at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recent vim version has a **builtin** package `cfilter` for this.

```
:packadd cfilter
:Lfilter! /pattern-to-delete/
```

This will remove all lines in location list (or Quickfix list if CFilter is used) that matches the pattern

See `:help CFilter`

Answer (score 2):

There's no builtin command, so you need to do a bit of scripting. Sort of this

```
:call getloclist(0)->filter('v:val.text !~? "test"')->setloclist(0)
```

Alternatively, you may want to search through github for relevant plugins, e.g. [github.com/search topic:vim topic:quickfix](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Avim+topic%3Aquickfix) or [github.com/search topic:vim topic:quickfix-window](https://github.com/search?q=topic%3Avim+topic%3Aquickfix-window) and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Is the loclist coming from the result of running `:make` ?   If so, then you can add to the `errorformat` setting using `%-G<pattern>` to ignore all error lines matching `<pattern>`.

The `errorformat` setting may be a result of your filetype and the `:compile <compiler>` command.  There is a compiler file $VIMRUNTIME/compiler/javac.vim which you might be using.  That file sets `errorformat` like this:

```
CompilerSet errorformat=%E%f:%l:\ %m,%-Z%p^,%-C%.%#,%-G%.%#
```